# How to find queries not using indexes or slow in mongodb

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

is there a way to find queries in mongodb that are not using Indexes or are SLOW? In MySQL that is possible with the following settings inside configuration file:

```
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 1
log_slow_queries = /tmp/slowmysql.log
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The equivalent approach in MongoDB would be to use the [query profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) to track and diagnose slow queries.

With profiling enabled for a database, slow operations are written to the `system.profile` capped collection (which by default is 1Mb in size).  You can adjust the threshold for slow operations (by default 100ms) using the [`slowms` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--slowms).

Comment: or you can do the following: mongo localhost:27017 and write in the console db.setProfilingLevel(2,10) - this will print in the log all queries which took more than 10 ms to perform

Comment: @Bestmacros yes, that's the "query profiler" suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 17):

First, you must set up your profiling, specifying what the log level that you want. The 3 options are:

- 0 - logger off
- 1 - log slow queries
- 2 - log all queries

You do this by running your `mongod` deamon with the `--profile` options:

`mongod --profile 2 --slowms 20`

With this, the logs will be written to the `system.profile` collection, on which you can perform queries as follows:

- find all logs in some collection, ordering by ascending timestamp:

`db.system.profile.find( { ns:/<db>.<collection>/ } ).sort( { ts: 1 } );`

- looking for logs of queries with more than 5 milliseconds:

`db.system.profile.find( {millis : { $gt : 5 } } ).sort( { ts: 1} );`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following two mongod options. The first option fails queries not using index (V 2.4 only), the second records queries slower than some ms threshold (default is 100ms)

```
--notablescan

Forbids operations that require a table scan.

--slowms <value>

Defines the value of “slow,” for the --profile option. The database logs all slow queries to the log, even when the profiler is not turned on. When the database profiler is on, mongod the profiler writes to the system.profile collection. See the profile command for more information on the database profiler.
```

Comment: So in the case --notablescan is provided - the query will be rejected by mongod? Will it be logged in system.profile collection?

Comment: In case of `--notablescan` an error will be returned, and you will see in the log something such as `query db.coll query: { whatever } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 exception: table scans not allowed: db.coll`

Comment: Note that you should only use {{--notablescan}} in a development environment.  There are many simple admin tasks that require table scans (i.e. seeing a list of collections or updating non-indexed fields), so enabling this option can have unexpected consequences.

Comment: I would consider both of these options the wrong options in a ev envo, clearly you wanna toggle the log level from within the app/console and use that to log certain queries instead of having to reset the deamon in order to do this kind of stuff, also the no table scan will not log those queries but instead stop them

Comment: @Sammaye If you have `--notablescan` in dev from the start, there is nothing to be logged and forces development to use indexes

Comment: It forces the query to not run, the query won't magically use an index

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command line tool [mongotail](https://github.com/mrsarm/mongotail) to read the log from the profiler  within a console and with a more readable format.

First activate the profiler and set the threshold in milliseconds for the profile to consider an operation to be slow. In the following example the threshold is set to 10 milliseconds for a database named "sales":

```
$ mongotail sales -l 1
Profiling level set to level 1
$ mongotail sales -s 10
Threshold profiling set to 10 milliseconds
```

Then, to see in *"real time"* the slow queries, with some extra information like the time each query took, or how many registries it need to "walk" to find a particular result:

```
$ mongotail sales -f -m millis nscanned docsExamined
2016-08-11 15:09:10.930 QUERY   [ops] : {"deleted": {"$exists": false}, "prod_id": "367133"}. 8 returned. nscanned: 344502. millis: 12
2016-08-11 15:09:10.981 QUERY   [ops] : {"deleted": {"$exists": false}, "prod_id": "367440"}. 6 returned. nscanned: 345444. millis: 12
....
```

Comment: Nice tool! I was able to set it up quickly, and get some good benchmarks with a local copy of production database.

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody ends up here from Google on this old question, I found that `explain` really helped me fix specific queries that I could see were causing `COLLSCAN`s from the logs.

Example:

`db.collection.find().explain()`

This will let you know if the query is using a `COLLSCAN` (Basic Cursor) or an `index` (BTree), among other things.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Answer (score -4):

While you can obviously use Profiler a very neat feature of Mongo DB due to which I actually fall in love with it is Mongo DB MMS. 
Takes less than 60 seconds and can manage from anywhere. I am sure you will Love it.
https://mms.mongodb.com/