# how to find out the slow queries in mysql (mostly in Mariadb)

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, mongodb

I have few questions:

**1)** I am newbie to performance testing as a starting assignment I have to investigate the slow queries in `MariaDb version : 10.0.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server` .

I tried with these settings in the `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
long_query_time=1
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
```

And after doing that I could no start the database. I get a simple 
`starting MySQL....                                         [FAILED]` message.

I came across [Slow query log overview for mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/slow-query-log-overview/) which made a little sense :(

Can any one provide me a tutorial of how it should be done.

**2)** In my application we already use Hibernate for data layer, Does it even make sense to find out the slow query log in the above mentioned way ?

**3)** How can i achieve the same thing in the mongodb.? like to list out the most frequently used queries, Slow queries ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should check mysql error log (probably /var/log/(mysql/)mysqld.log) for exact error. But "log-slow-queries" is starting option name (and deprecated too), you should use [slow_query_log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log) with boolean value and [slow_query_log_file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file) for filename

Comment: I think proper settings are `slow_query_log=1`, 
`slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log`, 
`long_query_time=1`

Comment: @user1786423 You should definitively post that as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the help :). Why some one did down voted my query ? I will try to investigate further in the mysql log files.

Comment: @saka1029 hi can you explain the differences between slow_query_log=1 long_query_time=1 bit confused :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to answer:

When mysql won't start, as first thing you should check mysql error log (probably /var/log/(mysql/)mysqld.log) for exact error.

In your case "log-slow-queries" is starting option name (and deprecated too), you should use slow_query_log with boolean value and slow_query_log_file for filename.

- slow_query_log=1 means ENABLE logging
- long_query_time=1 means IF ENABLED log queries longer than 1 second

then there is
- log_queries_not_using_indexes=0/1 which, if enabled, will log even queries faster than 1s if they are not using indexes to locate rows

All these and other can be found with descriptions in [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html)

For MongoDB there seems to be profiler which is described in answers to this question [How to find queries not using indexes or slow in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18451681)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will try as you have suggested. But would wait for some other inputs as well regarding the mongodb.

Comment: @rockyit86 check updated answer, mongodb was already answered quite well in there as it seems

Comment: In my opinion, `log_queries_not_using_indexes=1` is virtually useless while cluttering the slowlog.

Comment: @RickJames for better usage of log_queries_not_using_indexes I should probably add something about [min_examined_row_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_min_examined_row_limit) but not sure if it is OK to edit accepted answer